# Pipe not working with For loop in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a command that is not working.

Here it is:

```
mkdir \output & for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext -enc UTF-8 "%i" ".\output\%~ni.txt"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: excuse my ignorance...  where is the `pipe` in your command?

Comment: the & after mkdir \output

Comment: Path `.\output` referred to in `for … ".\output\%~ni.txt"` could be not the same as path `\output` referred to in `mkdir \output`. Note (missing or surplus) leading `.` dot (full stop character).

Answer (score 0):

First off, `&` is an ampersand.  `|` is a pipe.  The ampersand (`&`) allows you to run multiple commands on a single line.  The pipe (`|`) redirects the output of one command into another command.  Thus, the title of your question doesn't reflect your actual question.

Second, `.\` is current directory, and `\` is root directory.  Try using it with the `cd` command:

`cd .\` will do nothing, as it will "change" to the current directory.
`cd \`  will take you to the root folder, no matter how many folders deep you are.

The problem is that you're using different `output` folders in each command.  When you `mkdir \output`, it is creating a folder called `output` at the root of whatever drive you're in, like `c:\output`.  Later, you reference `.\output` which points to an `output` folder *in your current directory*, like `c:\users\myUserName\output`.

Here's what your command should look like:

```
mkdir .\output & for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext -enc UTF-8 "%i" ".\output\%~ni.txt"
```

Further, you might find more extensive help at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd